# Selecting unique values from a column and look for respective associated data from other dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**This** is for anyone if they are looking for a solution of such kind of a problem. I will try to explain the problem here and put the answer after that.

**Question**

I have `two csv` files (`file1.csv` and `file2.csv`): in which `cookieid` column is common in both. When I load it in dataframe it looks like this for ex:

```
file1.csv


col1  col2  col3 CookieID
a0   b1     c1   12
a1   b2     c2   13
a2   b3     c3   12
a1   b1     c1   145
a3   b4     c2   555

file2.csv

col4  col9  col55 CookieID colsales
Aba   xxx   yyy   12       567
bab   bhh   jjj   13        0
ccc   kkk   lll   222       67
Aba   xxx   yyy   1         6
ccc   kkk   jjj   666       90
```

**Task**: Need to make separate files for each `CookieID` with all their information in it from both the files. For ex:

I read from `file1.csv` and `file2.csv`. I select my first `cookieid` which is `12` and make a file `12.csv` (or any other suitable name) and inside it I put `a0  b1  c1 a2  b3  c3 Aba xxx yyy 567`. i.e values of rows where that `cookieid` is present from both the files.

**Solution** - Provided below for the community. It can be implemented if you want to find out the cookie journey from your dataset.

Comment: Thanks for sharing what you found. No need to get into the history. In a year, when someone comes to this post from a Google search it will just be annoying noise to them. Make your posts about the technical problem, and nothing but.

Comment: I did this because in the discussion someone pointed out my inability to learn something for more than half a year by pointing out my history.- which was not the case actually. Thanks for editing anyway :) @JoshCaswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string


DATA_FILE1 = 'file1.csv'
## encodings vary from file to file
df1 = pd.read_csv(DATA_FILE1,sep=',',encoding='ISO-8859-1')
DATA_FILE2 = 'file2.csv'
df2 = pd.read_csv(DATA_FILE2,sep=',',encoding='ISO-8859-1')

#creating a list of unique cookieids from both the files
cookielist =[]

uniqcookie1 = df1["CookieID"].unique()
uniqcookie2 = df2["CookieID"].unique()

for i in uniqcookie1:
    cookielist.append(i)
for j in uniqcookie2:
    cookielist.append(j)

for i in cookielist:
    dfout1 = df1.loc[df1['CookieID'] == i]
    dfout2 = df2.loc[df2['CookieID'] == i]
    bigdata = pd.concat([dfout1, dfout2], axis=1)
    k = bigdata.loc[:, bigdata.columns != 'CookieID']
    k.to_csv(str(i)+".txt",header=None, index=None, sep=' ', mode='a')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also use solution with `set`s for write only common rows in both `DataFrame` by `CookieID` column:

```
DATA_FILE1 = 'file1.csv'
df1 = pd.read_csv(DATA_FILE1,sep=',',encoding='ISO-8859-1',index_col=['CookieID'])
DATA_FILE2 = 'file2.csv'
df2 = pd.read_csv(DATA_FILE2,sep=',',encoding='ISO-8859-1', index_col=['CookieID'])

cookieset = set(df1.index).intersection(df2.index)
print (cookieset)
{12, 13}

for i in cookieset:
    dfout1 = df1.loc[[i]].values.ravel()
    dfout2 = df2.loc[[i]].values.ravel()
    bigdata = np.concatenate([dfout1, dfout2])
    print (bigdata)
    k = pd.DataFrame([bigdata])
    k.to_csv(str(i)+".txt",header=None, index=None, sep=' ')
```

Comment: Cheers @jezrael. I am sure there are multiple ways :)

Comment: btw instead of `df1 = pd.read_csv(DATA_FILE1,sep=',',encoding='ISO-8859-1',index_col=['CookieID'])` its better to load every column like I did below, because I need the data from all the columns.

Comment: Yes, but why use `k = bigdata.loc[:, bigdata.columns != 'CookieID']` for remove `CookieID` column?

Comment: Removing that so that when I put all the information of that particular cookieid in the txt file, I put all the informations other than the cookieID itself, coz that's the name of the file. @jezrael

Comment: @user1111 - OK, I think my code do same way - instead filtering select by index. And one thing, do you try your sample data in you solution? Because if same `CookieID` it create 2 rows. And also your solution create files for all `CookieID`, not only for common. so the best is it change in question.

Comment: @user1111 - I think you are not interested about answer, so can I delete it?

Comment: Hey, @jezrael, I am sure its a great answer and I didn't say anything like that. It's always good to have multiple solutions for a question, any part can help anyone. Lets keep it this way. Please don't delete anything :)